# How can I use the new bs4() theme in bookdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

How can I use the `bs4` theme in bookdown, such as the one used for the [R4DS book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz)

In the `_output.yaml` I see the following code, but it doesn't work with my project.

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  theme:
    primary: "#637238"
  repo: https://github.com/hadley/r4ds
  includes:
    in_header: [ga_script.html]
```

and I get this error when I attempt to build the book

```
Error: 'bs4_book' is not an exported object from 'namespace:bookdown'
Execution halted
```

Comment: By installating the development version from the github repo.: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown

Comment: Did you install the `R4DS` package that contains the code for the book format? you can install it by `devtools::install_github("hadley/r4ds")`

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it to work by doing the following:

Run the following

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/bslib")
install.packages("downlit")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/bookdown")
```

Change the `_output.yaml` to the following:

```
bookdown::bs4_book:
  theme:
    primary: "#637238"
```

Comment: `bookdown` for building the document, `bslib` for the `bookdown::bs4_book` itself and `downlit` because of `Error: Must install the following packages to use bs4_book() * downlit`.

Comment: I think that the following line is enough, `devtools::install_github('rstudio/bookdown@bs4-book-encoding', force = TRUE)`